# Make compatible ocaml, camlp4, ppx, node, js_of_ocaml, ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, opam, camlp4, js-of-ocaml, ppx

After installing `npm` and `node`, compiling OCaml files with `js_of_ocaml` gave errors, thus I did `opam switch reinstall system`:

```
:testweb $ opam switch reinstall system
Your system compiler has been changed. Do you want to upgrade your OPAM installation ? [Y/n] y

=-=- Upgrading system -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
[WARNING] base-ocamlbuild.base is not available because it requires OCaml >= 3.10 & < 4.03. Skipping.
[WARNING] camlp4.4.02+system is not available because your system doesn't comply with preinstalled &
      ocaml-version >= "4.02" & ocaml-version < "4.03". Skipping.
[WARNING] ppx_tools.4.02.3 is not available because your system doesn't comply with ocaml-version >=
      "4.02.0" & ocaml-version < "4.03.0". Skipping.
The following dependencies couldn't be met:
  - deriving -> camlp4
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - camlp4 is not available because your system doesn't comply with ocaml-version >= "4.04".

No solution found, exiting
The former package state can be restored with opam switch import "/Users/softtimur/.opam/backup/state-20160418124642.export" --switch system
```

Then, i realized `ocamlfind` did not work anymore:

```
:testweb $ ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T
-bash: /Users/softtimur/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind: No such file or directory
```

PS: `node --version` gives `v6.1.0`; `npm --version` gives `3.8.6`; `ocaml -version` gives `The OCaml toplevel, version 4.03.0`. 
`js_of_ocaml --version` was `2.7`, but after the `opam swtich reinstall system`, it gives `-bash: /Users/softtimur/.opam/system/bin/js_of_ocaml: No such file or directory`.

**Does anyone know what to do to make all these packages compatible?**

---

**Earlier:** Here were the compilation errors after installing `npm` and `node`, and before doing `opam switch reinstall system`:

```
:testweb $ ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T
Failure("Ast_mapper: OCaml version mismatch or malformed input")
File "cubes.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: /Users/softtimur/.opam/system/lib/js_of_ocaml/./ppx_js '/var/folders/fn/0rmvqqbs4k76lg5g6b7kll100000gn/T/camlppxffe989' '/var/folders/fn/0rmvqqbs4k76lg5g6b7kll100000gn/T/camlppx02e06a'
```

Another way also gave an error:

```
:testweb $ ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml -syntax camlp4o -package js_of_ocaml.syntax -linkpkg -o cubes.byte cubes.ml
Fatal error: unknown C primitive `caml_is_printable'
File "cubes.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: camlp4 '-I' '/usr/local/lib/ocaml/camlp4' '-I' '/Users/softtimur/.opam/system/lib/js_of_ocaml' '-parser' 'o' '-parser' 'op' '-printer' 'p' 'pa_js.cmo'  'cubes.ml' > /var/folders/fn/0rmvqqbs4k76lg5g6b7kll100000gn/T/ocamlpp8b28e8
```

---

**Initially:**
My initial goal is to write and compile `cubes.ml` such that 1) it wraps an OCaml function to make a JS function that can be called in web; 2) the OCaml function and the bytecode can be tested in a command line under Linux.

`cubes.ml` is as follows:

```
let () =
  let oneArgument (a: int) = a + 100 in
  Js.Unsafe.global##.jsOneArgument := Js.wrap_callback oneArgument;
  print_string "hello\n";
  exit 0
```

Then, `ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T` should generate `T` such that `./T` should return `hello`. And `js_of_ocaml T -o cubes.js` should generate `cubes.js` such that the function `jsOneArgument` of `cubes.js` can well be called by other JS or HTML files.

Before I messed up the packages, `./T` returned `Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!`, that is why i installed `npm`, `node`, etc...

Comment: Isn't `$ node cubes.js` enough?

Comment: do you mean run `node cubes.js` in the command line? could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Yes. node.js outputs `hello` in a command line under Linux.

Comment: I see what you mean... please see my updates...

Comment: Perhaps a system compiler is updated when install node. `opam switch reinstall system` may be needed.

Comment: i just did `opam swtich reinstall system`, it looks worrying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to OCaml 4.02.3:

```
opam switch 4.02.3
```

Then,

```
eval `opam config env`
```

Then,

```
opam install ppx_tools js_of_ocaml
```

As a result, `ocamlfind ocamlc -package js_of_ocaml.ppx -linkpkg cubes.ml -o T` generates `T`, and `js_of_ocaml T -o cubes.js` generates `cubes.js`. `node cubes.js` does return `hello`.

However, `./T` still returns `Unimplemented Javascript primitive caml_pure_js_expr!`, I am going to open another post for that...

Comment: Note that it should be ``eval `opam config env` `` (backquote) or `eval $(opam config env)` (alternate bash syntax), simple quotes won't do.

Comment: `eval $(opam env)` does the job, too